# How do I optimize Upsert (Update and Insert) operation within SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am not a DBA but I do work for a small company as the IT person.  I have to replicate a database from staging to production.  I have created an SSIS package to do this but it takes hours to run.  This isn't a large data warehouse type of project, either, it's a pretty straightforward `Upsert`.  I'm assuming that I am the weak link in how I designed it.

Here's my procedure:

1. Truncate staging tables (`EXECUTE SQL TASK`)
2. Pull data from a development table into staging (`Data Flow Task`)
3. Run a data flow task

   1. *`OLE DB Source`*
   2. *`Conditional Split Transformation`* (Condition used: `[!]ISNULL(is_new_flag)`)
   3. If new insert, if existing update

The data flow task is mimicked a few times to change tables/values but the flow is the same.  I've read several things about OLE DB components being slow to updates being slow and have tried a few things but haven't gotten it to run very quickly.

I'm not sure what other details to give, but I can give anything that's asked for.

Comment: Have you looked at the Merge statement? Maybe you could try that out if it helps.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just Backup from development and Restore to Staging?

Comment: RBarryYoung, I know it sounds stupid but the production DB is in a Colo and transferring files is a pain through the FW whereas DB connections are not an issue.  It's just more reliable.

Comment: rvphx, I was using the merge statement at first.  I then found that using a staging table is known to be a faster alternative.  However, I may have misunderstood those articles as billinkc has perhaps made me aware.

Comment: @Tim I am pretty sure that by the time you are done, you will find this approach to a much bigger pain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Sample package using SSIS 2008 R2 that inserts or updates using batch operation:

Here is a sample package written in *`SSIS 2008 R2`* that illustrates how to perform insert, update between two databases using batch operations.

- Using *`OLE DB Command`* will slow down the update operations on your package because it does *not* perform batch operations. Every row is updated individually.

The sample uses two databases namely *`Source`* and *`Destination`*. In my example, both the databases reside on the server but the logic can still be applied for databases residing on different servers and locations.

I created a table named *`dbo.SourceTable`* in my source database *`Source`*.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable](
    [RowNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL
)
```

Also, created two tables named *`dbo.DestinationTable`* and *`dbo.StagingTable`* in my destination database *`Destination`*.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DestinationTable](
    [RowNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StagingTable](
    [RowNumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL
) 
GO
```

Inserted about 1.4 million rows in the table *`dbo.SourceTable`* with unique values into `RowNumber` column. The tables *`dbo.DestinationTable`* and *`dbo.StagingTable`* were empty to begin with. All the rows in the table *`dbo.SourceTable`* have the flag **`IsActive`** set to false.

[image: Row counts - 1]

Created an SSIS package with two OLE DB connection managers, each connecting to `Source` and `Destination` databases. Designed the Control Flow as shown below:

- First `Execute SQL Task` executes the statement **`TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.StagingTable`** against the destination database to truncate the staging tables.
- Next section explains how the `Data Flow Task` is configured.
- Second `Execute SQL Task` executes the below given SQL statement that updates data in *`dbo.DestinationTable`* using the data available in *`dbo.StagingTable`*, assuming that there is a unique key that matches between those two tables. In this case, the unique key is the column *`RowNumber`*.

#### Script to update:

```
UPDATE      D 
SET         D.CreatedOn = S.CreatedOn
        ,   D.ModifiedOn = S.ModifiedOn 
FROM        dbo.DestinationTable D 
INNER JOIN  dbo.StagingTable S 
ON          D.RowNumber = S.RowNumber
```

[image: Control Flow]

I have designed the Data Flow Task as shown below.

- *`OLE DB Source`* reads data from *`dbo.SourceTable`* using the SQL command **`SELECT RowNumber,CreatedOn, ModifiedOn FROM Source.dbo.SourceTable WHERE IsActive = 1`**
- *`Lookup transformation`* is used to check if the RowNumber value already exists in the table *`dbo.DestinationTable`*
- If the record **does not** exist, it will be redirected to the *`OLE DB Destination`* named as **`Insert into destination table`**, which inserts the row into *`dbo.DestinationTable`*
- If the record **exists**, it will be redirected to the *`OLE DB Destination`* named as **`Insert into staging table`**, which inserts the row into *`dbo.StagingTable`*. This data in staging table will be used in the second `Execute SQL Task to perform batch update.

[image: Data Flow tab]

To activate few more rows for OLE DB Source, I ran the below query to activate some records

```
UPDATE  dbo.SourceTable 
SET     IsActive = 1 
WHERE   (RowNumber % 9 = 1) 
OR      (RowNumber % 9 = 2)
```

[image: Update rows - 1]

First execution of the package looked as shown below. All the rows were directed to destination table because it was empty. The execution of the package on my machine took about `3 seconds`.

[image: Execution 1]

[image: Execution time 1]

Ran the row count query again to find the row counts in all three table.

[image: Row counts - 2]

To activate few more rows for OLE DB Source, I ran the below query to activate some records

```
UPDATE  dbo.SourceTable 
SET     IsActive = 1 
WHERE   (RowNumber % 9 = 3) 
OR      (RowNumber % 9 = 5) 
OR      (RowNumber % 9 = 6) 
OR      (RowNumber % 9 = 7)
```

[image: Row counts - 3]

Second execution of the package looked as shown below. `314,268 rows` that were previously inserted during first execution were redirected to staging table. `628,766 new rows` were directly inserted into the destination table. The execution of the package on my machine took about `12 seconds`. `314,268 rows` in destination table were updated in the second Execute SQL Task with the data using staging table.

[image: Execution - 2]

[image: Execution time - 2]

Ran the row count query again to find the row counts in all three table.

[image: Row counts - 3]

I hope that gives you an idea to implement your solution.

Comment: So the Lookup is now the bottleneck. No problem when you have 943 034 rows, however it's slower when you have like 500 000 000 rows (the index is then 4 or 5 levels deep, so you have 500M x 4 = 2 bln logical reads). I would just try to insert and if it fails with integrity constraint violation error, then just assume it's an existing row and accumulate those in the staging table, as you described.

Answer (score 8):

The two things I'd look at are your inserts (ensure you are using either the "Table or View - fast load" or "Table name or view name variable - fast load") and your updates.

As you have correctly determined, the update logic is usually where performance falls down and that is due to the OLE DB component firing singleton updates for each row flowing through it. The usual approach people take to overcome this is to write all the updates to a staging table, much as your Insert logic does. Then follow up your `Data Flow Task` with an `Execute SQL Task` to perform a bulk Update.

If you are in the mind of acquiring 3rd party tools, PragmaticWorks offers an [Upsert destination](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory/Features/UpsertDestination%28BatchUpdateOrInsert%29.aspx)

Comment: This is interesting.  To be a bit dumb, how would I go about doing the batch update?  I only know of the singletons.

Comment: The OLE DB Component doesn't offer a batch update option. If you use it, you're firing single statements. The OLE DB Destination can also operate in the same fashion if you do **not** select the fast load option. I'll try and update with pictures after these meetings

Comment: I think I get it, It'll be a bit before I can test it, but I think this'll do it.

Comment: Personally, I'd accept Siva's answer. Far more detailed as this meeting is sucking my will to live

Comment: @billinkc I wish there was some way we could downvote your meeting :-(

Comment: You both deserve major Kudos.  I just tested it with one data flow and it's screaming fast compared to before.  I gave you both upvotes but I didn't see Siva's answer until now, so I'll keep the check with billinkc