# Update Data in table. Lookup ? Merge?

Tags: ssis

I am in need of a solution.

I am supposed to load the data of a table from `PROD` server to `UAT`. If records are missing in `UAT`, load the missing rows. How Should i go about it ?

Second Problem.

I am fetching some data `(EmpId,NAME,CreditCardNumebr)` from some text files. They are collaborated based on `EmpId` from a table in `SQL Server` `(ID,Address,ContactNumber)`.
The combined information `(ID,NAME,ContactNumber,Address,Creditcard)` have to be loaded in the main table. IF the record doesn't exist, `ADD`. But if some information is missing in the fields of the records present, `UPDATE`.

I was able to get some information from Lookup Video session uploaded.
But not able to do the required things.

Please help.

Comment: Go thru this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066982/how-can-i-use-merge-statement-across-multiple-database-servers

Answer (score 1):

To join the data of your two sources you should use a "merge join" component or a "Lookup" component. It depends how many rows you've in both sources. Once your two sources have been joined you should write this result in a staging table. Then apply a sql merge statement between the staging and the final destination tables.

Comment: I really recommend that you challenge this requirement to not use staging tables. Why such an requirement? Anyway, if for good reasons you cannot then you'll need to perform a lookup or a Merge Join (left) to detect if your rows nned to be inserted or updated. For the row needing an insert you should apply an OleDB destination for rows with updates you've no other alternative than a OleDB Command.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for but if it is incremental loads, you can import the data to a "Stage" table and write a query to do a update insert into the active tables. Let it compare the Primary keys. If it is the same, test the fields for changes and update, if not, insert new row.

Hope it help.

Comment: M Afraid Not A solution i am looking for. Moreover The SQL command is full blocking i suppose , so won't be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't have a Staging table. That is a requirement. 
Anyway I did make a partial solution for the problem.

We need to use 2 LookUp Transformations to get the desired result. 
1 For collabarating data of the Flat file and the table that holds the partial data.
1 For checking for record existance based on the business key (i.e. ID (Primary Key))

Flat File Source --> LookUp (For collabaration)  --> LookUp (For record check)  --> OleDb Destination

The records that comes out in the (NO Match Output) are filled in the table.
I need to find out the way to update the records (Which come in the Match output)

If you guys can provide me a solution for it , it will be highly appreciated.