# How to run a SQL merge statement in SSIS using data from an OLEDB source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have two databases used by two different systems that are required to share a set of data (the flow of data is one way from one system to the other). The system that receives teh data imports it using SSIS packages. The table structure and column names for the tables that contain shared data are the same on both databases.

Using SSIS I want to be able to take a subset of the data from a table in the first system. For example

```
SELECT ProductId, col2, col3, col4 from Products WHERE modifiedDate > @ThresholdDate
```

Then I want to take the data from this query and use a SQL merge statement to either add or update the data in the other database depending on whether or not the ProductId matches.

I have written a merge statement in an Execute SQL task before, but this was possible because both databases were on the same server. I don't want to have to use sp_addlinkedserver, I would just like to have a OLE DB Source that gets the data, and to pass this data to some SSIS component that I can then use to run the merge statement.

Is this possible or would I need to first store the data in a temp table before running the merge statement?

Comment: actually this question seems to describe pretty well how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066982/how-can-i-use-merge-statement-across-multiple-database-servers

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a Foreach Loop Container, having put the original query results into an object variable. Then transferring the output into separate variables and running the merge query one row at a time.

However I’d imagine your best way to do this would be create a temp table as you mentioned. Transfer the data across to the temp table and then run the merge from that. It is undoubtedly going to be quicker.